# Get Document Class Name

Tags: c++, mfc, document-view

How can I get class name of a document in my program. I mean, I have done this:

```
pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(
   IDR_FRAMETYPE,
   RUNTIME_CLASS(CFrameDoc2D),
   RUNTIME_CLASS(CEditorChildFrame),
   RUNTIME_CLASS(CFrameView));
gl_pDocTemplateManager->AddTemplateInfo("CMyDoc", eStructure);
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
```

I want to get `CMyDoc` string in another project (.dll) of my MSVC solution via `CDocument` class. I can't cast to a specific document class due to cyclic dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `AddTemplateInfo()` does, it does not seem to be a standard MFC function.

To get the name of the class, you could use something like:

```
CRuntimeClass *pClass = pDoc->GetRuntimeClass();
if (pClass != NULL)
    TRACE(_T("Document class = %S\n"), pClass->m_lpszClassName);
```

NOTE: `m_lpszClassName` is ASCII (`LPCSTR`) and the code above assumes your project is based on Unicode -- otherwise, change `%S` to `%s`.

Comment: A more reliable version of the `TRACE` invocation would be: `TRACE(_T("Document class = %s\n"), CA2CT(pClass->m_lpzsClassName));` This will not rely on project settings and will always produce correct code. See [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) for documentation.